# natural projection on a slice

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I'm currently studying Warner's book "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups". Within the proof of the Frobenius Theorem he is constructing a slice $S$ of a coordinate system $(V,y_1,\dotsc,y_d)$ on a $d$-manifold, where $S$ is given by $y_1=0$. He then says that we have a "natural projection in the $y$-coordinate system" $\pi: V\rightarrow S$. It's probably completely obvious but how is this map defined?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$\pi(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_d) = (0,y_2,\dots,y_d)$

Comment: ...but the $y_i$s are maps $V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: ...and $\pi:V\rightarrow S$ so why is your map well-defined?

Comment: The notation means that $\pi$ maps the point $p \in V$ with coordinates $(y_1(p),y_2(p),\dots,y_d(p))$ to the point $\pi(p)\in V$ with coordinates $(0,y_2(p),\dots,y_d(p))$. And since $S \subset V$ is defined by the condition $y_1=0$, in fact $\pi(p) \in S$.